# encoding string that has been decoded with %' to unicode

Tags: python, unicode

html POST method decoded my string like this:

> Ostrołęka => Ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka

How do I encode it into readable form in Python?

Sorry for possible duplicate.

EDIT: Solution in 'possible duplicate' doesn't solve above problem

Comment: solution there doesn't solve my problem

Comment: That solution works for entities like `&pound;` but not `%`-escaped values.  For that, you want `urllib.unquote()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 2:

```
from urllib import unquote
x = unquote('Ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka')
```

Python 3:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
x = unquote('Ostro%C5%82%C4%99ka')
```

Comment: I'm using Python3.6: AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'unquote'

Comment: In python3 it is `urllib.parse.unquote`

Comment: It works now! Thanks